# Passing objects to UserControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a CustomControl to which I can pass an "Person" object. How can I pass the person object to the custom control like this `PersonDetails="{Binding Path=Person}"` to the CusomControl ?

instead of passing `Address="{Binding Path=Person.Address}"Address="{Binding Path=Person.FirstName}"`  ect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare PersonDetails as a [dependency property](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html).

Then you can use it as any other WPF control property - both in XAML (including data binding) and in code.